# JSONDecoder can't decode on real device when it runs fine on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have a JSONDecoder that works on simulator, but it can't decode the same data when running on real device, please help.
This error will happen when running on real device:

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(
  codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), 
  CodingKeys(stringValue: "market_cap", intValue: nil)], 
  debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <16541228553> does not fit in Int.", 
  underlyingError: nil))
```

I think 16541228553 should fit in Int?
It fits when running on simulator.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You note in the tags that this is an Apple Watch. I'm guessing it's a Series 3, which is a 32-bit platform. This is a 34-bit number, so it doesn't fit.

The Simulator does not emulate hardware. It's a 64-bit Mac app that links libraries that match the device SDK. So on Simulator, it doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information about the question but I guess the `market_cap` property in your model is `Int`.

Changing with `Decimal` would fix the problem

```
 class YourClass: Codable {
   var market_cap: Decimal
   ....
 }
```